# How can i debug in visual studio as command line?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

I hav my execuatable produced by command line building.

I want to debug it in command line itself as like as gdb does in linux.

Also i want run my program in Visual studio GUI from command line options..

How can i do that?

Comment: What language/framework are you debugging?

Comment: C language code written in gvim editor and built using visual studio 2005 by commandline 'make ' option.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure it is compiled in the debug version.  Run the program.  Then "Attach to Process" from VS tools menu.

You can also specify the runtime options when running the debugger (it's in the project properties).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that VS has a pure command line mode, but you could use CDB/NTSD.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc266320.aspx

It is what lots of developers at MS do.